# InstallShield creates MSI even though build has errors

Tags: build, installshield

When I'm compiling ism project to create MSI, its still creates the MSI even though I have build errors.

The reason I need it NOT to be created is for build verification.
Instead of checking the build log for errors, I will just check the existence of the MSI.

Does anybody know how can I achieve that?
**EDIT:**
I'm using ISCmdBld tool to build MSIs. This is the command line I'm running to build where the environment variables are being set before running this command:

```
IsCmdBld -p "%FULL_PROJECT_FILENAME%" -a %BUILDMODE% -r %PRODUCT% -o "%MMSEARCHPATH%" | tee /A "%FULL_PROJECT_LOG_FILENAME%"
```

Comment: How are you building the installer?  Are you doing desktop builds or do you have an automated build system?

Comment: @ChristopherPainter I'm using ISCmdBld tool for building. for example: IsCmdBld -p "%FULL_PROJECT_FILENAME%" -a %BUILDMODE% -r %PRODUCT% -o "%MMSEARCHPATH%" | tee /A "%FULL_PROJECT_LOG_FILENAME%"

Answer (score 1):

If you are compiling using IsCmdBld.exe, you should add the `-x` option, so that the build is stopped if an error occurs.

You also can use it combined with `-w`, which makes each warning becomes considered as an error (and thus, each warning encountered also stops the build).

More information about `IsCmdBld.exe` : http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield16helplib/ISCmdBldParam.htm

I hope this helps.

Comment: And if you are using InstallShield's MSBuild Targets file you can set the StopOnFirstError attribute to true.

Comment: @ChristopherPainter Hi, Thanks for your answer. I'm familiar with the stop on first error. However its still creating the MSI. i dont want the MSI to be created at all on errors...Do you know any other option ? Thanks again!

Comment: Options depend on your answer to my question above.

Answer (score 1):

Your build automation should check the exit code from ISCmdBld.exe. If the exit code is a failure, don't archive the output.

Comment: Exactly! You can even use "-s" for silent mode to reduce console output.